# converting iPad app to iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I'm currently working on an iPad-specific application.
Since I don't use interface builder, every view element is using CGRectMake with specific numbers for its position and size.

so I was wondering,
if I use the same exact code on iPhone, do these numbers scale accordingly?
or should I re-insert the numbers for all the view elements?
If the latter case, is there any easy way to change it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGRect` coordinates are absolute, so your subviews will not automatically scale down to the iPhone.  If you run your code on an iPhone, you will see only the upper-left corner of your iPad layout.

You can pretty easily write a helper method to take the original `CGRect` values and scale them down for the iPhone layout.  However, if you're also drawing text you'll need to scale down the font sizes as well (which probably won't work, so you'll still need to deal with the text in a possible not-automated way).

I'm doing essentially the same thing right now, writing a single app that runs on both iPad and iPhone and scales itself in code to the available dimensions.  I'm generally setting up the view layouts as a float proportion of the available screen size, and then converting those proportions to `CGRect` before rendering.

Kudos on not using Interface Builder by the way - IB may be the most ridiculous atrocity I've ever seen in the programming world (even worse than classic ASP, which is saying something).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change your numbers for your iPhone app. The points that `CGRectMake` uses are pixels and don't scale, with the exception of HD devices like the iPhone 4.

Honestly, the iPad is such a different device that your UI probably needs to be heavily modified to take advantage of the extra screen space.

Comment: so they do scale for iPhone 4 and iPod touch? because those are the devices I would need my app to be converted for...

Comment: Not the iPod touch. It still has a "low def" screen. The only device currently sold that has an HD screen is the iPhone 4. Even then, it doesn't scale like you're talking about. You may want to read up on the [Retina Display](http://globalmoxie.com/blog/designing-for-iphone4-retina-display.shtml).